# When a line of codes is too long, how do I break up the line without \

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pep8

I have created a few of classes, but these classes have names that are too long (eq: `NegativeChannelMetalOxideSemiconductorFieldEffectTransistor`). I want to make a new line with `\` in python, but in this case it is ugly. In general in Python, when code is too long, using `\` to make a new line is a good choice, but it will not work here.  How should I shorten or break up these lines?

[image: figure1]

[image: figure3]

Comment: Don't link to images of code. Instead, copy the ***text*** of the code directly into your question, correctly formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some suggestions on shortening this line without a `\`:

```
class NegativeChannelMetalOxideSemiconductorFieldEffectTransistor(MetalOxideSemiconductorFieldEffectTransistor):
```

You can break a line inside of braces `[]`, `{}`, `()` without using a `\`.

```
class NegativeChannelMetalOxideSemiconductorFieldEffectTransistor(
    MetalOxideSemiconductorFieldEffectTransistor):
```

You can use acronyms or abbreviations:

```
class NegativeChannelMetalOxideSemiconductorFET(MetalOxideSemiconductorFET):
```

or:

```
class NegativeChannelMOSFET(MOSFET):
```

Comment: thank you for answering my problem,I think I have knew what to do when encounter similar problems